# Can't set Android emulator date - stuck on 1/1/1970

Tags: android, adb, emulation, virtualization, android-virtual-device

I am having trouble manually setting the date on my android emulator.

I am using an ARM AVD which is running on a Windows 10 Virtual Machine (no Intel HAXM available), and the emulator is being run with the "-gpu swiftshader" option.

I tried setting the date both from the Android UI (the settings menu) and from the shell (adb date -s command with root privileges) with no success. The date keeps beeing stuck on 1/1/1970.

I Also tried changing my AVD's and the Android versions. I tried it on Android versions 2.3, 4.2, and 4.4. None of them worked.

What might be the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: For anyone else with this problem, rather than the mouse, try using the arrow keys and Enter key on your computer keyboard to navigate and set the emulator's date. Alternatively, in Terminal, you can try `adb shell date "12312359"` (MMDDhhmm).

Answer (score 0):

I think, some VirtualBox versions cause this problem. My Emulator also had been  gave this error.
Try uninstall virtualBox, install lower version like 3.*
And set a new Emulator.
hope it can fix.